# Распознавать объекты только в части видео(в реальном времени) в OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Есть видео(в реальном времени, задержку могу позволить 30 сек, ну а в крайней мере минуту) и нужно распознавать объекты в некой "зоне" **СЛОЖНОЙ ФОРМЫ**(не прямоугольной) в OpenCv.
**Можно ли как-то эту зону реализовать?**
Я придумал 2 костыля:

1. Кропать видео на несколько прямоугольных "зон" и отдельно их сканировать.
2. На "быстром монтаже" в питоне(если так можно конечно) закрашивать ненужную "зону"

Зона примерная:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB1tU.png

Comment: можете нарисовать эту сложную форму ? старый добрый прямоугольник ещё никогда не подводил.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB1tU.png

Comment: уточните, если объект будет в 2х зонах сразу, то он считается или нет ?

Comment: Допустим поставил 2 зоны как костыль(хотел изначально 1) тоесть объект должен быть 1 даже если их типо 2.считается но только 1 раз

Comment: Добавьте картинку полностью, а не по ссылке (в редакторе есть специальная кнопка)

Comment: Она криво работает или я кривой.(сегодня я на телефе)

Comment: Почему бы не сделать бинарную маску с зоной, размером с кадр.
Далее делать, перед распознаванием, bitwise_and кадра с маской.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png',0) #нужно нарисовать маску на отдельной картинке Какую область на изображении вы хотите обработать, эта область в маске должна быть белой, а все остальное - черной.
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
```

хотелось бы конечно маску к видео но буду делать по кадрово